how to put courses at the end of typed text quill focus
It is necessary that after the renderApp function is executed, the cursor should be at the end of the string
import store from "../../store/store.js";
import context from "../../store/context.js";
import { initQuill } from "../../services/quill.js";
import { renderApp } from "../../render/render-app.js";

export const handleInputTaskArea = () => {
    const areaElement = document.getElementById("task-area");
    const editor = initQuill(areaElement);

    editor.container.firstChild.innerHTML = store.tasks[store.active_task];
    editor.focus({ preventScroll: true });

    areaElement?.addEventListener("input", () => {
        if (context.isSent) {
            context.isSent = false;

            renderApp(context, ["update-task-editor"]);

            // Ensure the cursor is at the end of the editor content after renderApp
            setTimeout(() => {
                editor.focus();
                const length = editor.getLength();
                editor.setSelection(length - 1, length - 1, 'silent');
            }, 0);
        }
    });

    editor.on("text-change", () => {
        store.tasks[store.active_task] = editor.root.innerHTML;
    });
};


quill.focus({ preventScroll: true }); - it doesn't work
quill.focus({ preventScroll: true }); - it doesn't work
